# Give program/user rights for specific tasks

Tags: permissions, sudo, privileges

I'm writing a program that needs to perform some privileged operations without inserting any password, for example:

- use systemctl commands
- run superuser commands
- read/write files owned by root user

So far what I have been doing, is to create a sudoer file for the user running the program, allowing it to run some specific sudo commands without the need of the password.

Now I need to read/write some root files, for example I have to read /etc/shadow, and altough I could just add `cat /etc/shadow` to the sudoer file, I would prefer to just give my program (or to the user running the program) the permission to read it directly (i.e. to open and read the file in the program itself).

How can I achieve this?

Also, is it good to use the sudoer file like I am doing? Are there any better alternatives?

Lastly, I want to specify that I don't want to give my program/user total superuser permissions, just permissions for the specific tasks I need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Coding in what? If it's C etc, then you could make it setuid and drop the privs as soon as you no longer need them.

Comment: @Bib It's both Python and C++, so I would rather solve it "outside" the code

Comment: @Mdp11 The `suid` bit is "outside the code", since it is a filesystem option. Are the escalated privileges you need in the C++ or Python part (setuid doesn't work on scripts for security purposes)?

Comment: @jeremymeadows I need in both parts actually. Does the "suid" bit enable all sudo commands? Or can I limit the set it enables?

Comment: @Mdp11 It would escalate the privileges so that it could do essentially the same thing as calling it with `sudo ./a.out`, and there is a way to change the effective UID in a C/C++ program: [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setuid-Program-Example.html). Again, not sure how this would work with your Python part, but if you add you project structure to the question, I/somebody might be able to give a more specific answer (eg. C program does root operation, then calls Python...).